# python error where __str__ returns a NoneType

Tags: string, python-3.x, class, nonetype

```
class Pixel:
  """Representing a 'pixel' aka one character on the screen
  is mostly gonne be used in Map using a tuple location and a
  character that can be changed"""

  def __init__(self, char='#', location=(0,0)):
    assert type(char) == str
    assert type(location[0]) == int and type(location[1]) == int
    self.location = location
    self.x = self.location[0]
    self.y = self.location[1]
    self.char = char

  def __str__(self):
    return(self.char)



class Map:
  """Representing a map by having diffferent characters
  on different lines and being able to manipulate the 
  characters, thus playing a game"""

  def __init__(self, file=None):
    self.pixels = {}
    if not file:
      self.rows = 3
      self.colls = 3
      for r in range(self.rows):
        for c in range(self.colls):
          self.pixels[(r, c)] = Pixel('#', (r, c))

  def __str__(self):
    print(self.pixels)
    for c in range(self.colls):
      print('')
      for r in range(self.rows):
        print(self.pixels[(r, c)], end='')





a = Map()
print(a)
```

I am trying to make a class that defines a grid where each place in the grid has a character, but when I run the code I get an error that tells me that `__str__` returns a NoneType. I know I am not yet handeling file imput when initiating `Map` but that isn't the problem here, here is the output I got.

```
{(0, 1): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a3080>,
 (1, 2): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a3470>,
 (0, 0): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a3048>,
 (2, 0): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a34a8>,
 (1, 0): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a32b0>,
 (2, 2): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a3390>,
 (0, 2): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a30b8>,
 (2, 1): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a3358>,
 (1, 1): <__main__.Pixel object at 0x7f31612a32e8>}

###
###
###Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 45, in <module>
    print(a)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
exited with non-zero status
```

I am also confused why the print in `__str__` from `Map` refered me to the `__main__.Pixel` objects instead of using they `__str__` method, but that is probably just my lack of knowlage

what am I missing?

Comment: __str__ method should always return a String when the class is called.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `__repr__`. Also in `Map.__str__`, you are not returning anything.For ex

```
In [10]: class Test:
   ....:     def __str__(self):
   ....:         return "str"
   ....:     def __repr__(self):
   ....:         return "repr"
   ....:     

In [11]: t=Test()

In [12]: t
Out[12]: repr

In [13]: print(t)
str
```

Comment: will this help me with the `TypeError`or with the representation or `__main__.Pixel object`?

Comment: Yes. `__main__.Pixel object` will change to whatever returning in `Pixel.__repr__` method

Comment: Thanks, that problem is fixed :-)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to `return`anything, i had the `__str__`print everything i needed but i didn't return anything for my `print(a)`, thus i got a NoneType error.